# Stripe notification mechanism

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, subscriptions

I have a typical scenario like i have a video model which are paid.

I have stripe integrated for credit card processing. But the problem is how can i check if the user is subscribed and the users payment is not out of date before the user the watching video?

Any ideas how to accomplish this?
Any help would be appreciated.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a way to tell if the user is valid. You can do that by keeping track of amount owed, or by using a datetime field such as `last_paid_at` which you update when the user pays their bill.

In a before_filter for videos, check if the user is invalid. So if the balance > 0 or if it's been longer than a month since the last payment.

Check out [Stripe Webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to get notified when a payment goes through. Basically webhooks are endpoints where stripe can send you information.